# How to enable parquet in {arrow} in R?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

**TLDR; The {arrow} package in R doesn't have `parquet` enabled on my machine anymore - how can I enable it?**

I have been using the {arrow} library in R for a few years to read and write `parquet` files, but today it didn't work anymore and I'm not sure what caused it or what I can do to fix it.

#### What I encounter

First, on loading the package:

```r
library(arrow)
Some features are not enabled in this build of Arrow. Run `arrow_info()` for more information.

Attaching package: ‘arrow’
```

Running `arrow_info()` tells me that `parquet` and other formats are not enabled:

```r
arrow_info()
Arrow package version: 11.0.0.3

Capabilities:
               
dataset   FALSE
substrait FALSE
parquet   FALSE
json      FALSE
s3        FALSE
gcs       FALSE
utf8proc   TRUE
re2        TRUE
snappy     TRUE
gzip       TRUE
brotli     TRUE
zstd       TRUE
lz4        TRUE
lz4_frame  TRUE
lzo       FALSE
bz2        TRUE
jemalloc   TRUE
mimalloc   TRUE

Memory:
                  
Allocator mimalloc
Current    0 bytes
Max        0 bytes

Runtime:
                          
SIMD Level          avx512
Detected SIMD Level avx512

Build:
                                    
C++ Library Version           11.0.0
C++ Compiler              AppleClang
C++ Compiler Version 14.0.3.14030022
```

And just to make sure it is actually a problem, I tried using `write_parquet()`:

```r
write_parquet(my_data, path)

Error in parquet___WriterProperties___Builder__create() : 
  Cannot call parquet___WriterProperties___Builder__create(). See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html for help installing Arrow C++ libraries.
```

When (re)installing {arrow}, these are the logs:

```
install.packages("arrow")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/arrow_11.0.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3921484 bytes (3.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘arrow’ ...
files ‘tools/cpp/src/arrow/Testing/Temporary/CTestCostData.txt’, ‘tools/cpp/src/arrow/Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log’ are missing
** using staged installation
*** Arrow C++ libraries found via pkg-config at /usr/local/Cellar/apache-arrow/11.0.0_3/lib
**** Warning: library version mismatch
**** C++ is 11.0.0 but R is 11.0.0.3
**** If installation fails, upgrade the C++ library to match
**** or retry with ARROW_USE_PKG_CONFIG=false
PKG_CFLAGS= 
PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/apache-arrow/11.0.0_3/lib -larrow
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)’
using C++17
using SDK: ‘’
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RTasks.cpp -o RTasks.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c altrep.cpp -o altrep.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c array.cpp -o array.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c array_to_vector.cpp -o array_to_vector.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c arraydata.cpp -o arraydata.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c arrowExports.cpp -o arrowExports.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c bridge.cpp -o bridge.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c buffer.cpp -o buffer.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c chunkedarray.cpp -o chunkedarray.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c compression.cpp -o compression.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c compute-exec.cpp -o compute-exec.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c compute.cpp -o compute.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c config.cpp -o config.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c csv.cpp -o csv.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c dataset.cpp -o dataset.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c datatype.cpp -o datatype.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c expression.cpp -o expression.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c extension-impl.cpp -o extension-impl.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c feather.cpp -o feather.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c field.cpp -o field.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c filesystem.cpp -o filesystem.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c io.cpp -o io.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c json.cpp -o json.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c memorypool.cpp -o memorypool.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c message.cpp -o message.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c parquet.cpp -o parquet.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c r_to_arrow.cpp -o r_to_arrow.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c recordbatch.cpp -o recordbatch.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c recordbatchreader.cpp -o recordbatchreader.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c recordbatchwriter.cpp -o recordbatchwriter.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c safe-call-into-r-impl.cpp -o safe-call-into-r-impl.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c scalar.cpp -o scalar.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c schema.cpp -o schema.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c symbols.cpp -o symbols.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c table.cpp -o table.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c threadpool.cpp -o threadpool.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/cpp11/include' -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c type_infer.cpp -o type_infer.o
clang++ -std=gnu++17 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/xz/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o arrow.so RTasks.o altrep.o array.o array_to_vector.o arraydata.o arrowExports.o bridge.o buffer.o chunkedarray.o compression.o compute-exec.o compute.o config.o csv.o dataset.o datatype.o expression.o extension-impl.o feather.o field.o filesystem.o io.o json.o memorypool.o message.o parquet.o r_to_arrow.o recordbatch.o recordbatchreader.o recordbatchwriter.o safe-call-into-r-impl.o scalar.o schema.o symbols.o table.o threadpool.o type_infer.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/apache-arrow/11.0.0_3/lib -larrow -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.3.0_1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/00LOCK-arrow/00new/arrow/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (arrow)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rh/y9ws4bgj7x50twypcwtk2ypr0000gp/T/Rtmp6aUBmW/downloaded_packages’
```

#### What I've tried

- Restarting R
- Uninstalling, re-installing {arrow} and rebooting
- Installing arrow through homebrew
- Updating R, re-installing {arrow} and rebooting

My versions are:

- MacOS 13.3.1
- R 4.3.0
- Arrow 11.0.0.3
- C++ 11.0.0

Comment: Unfortunately, I started out the day on R 4.2.1, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I wonder if the logs when installing the app can be informative here. Can you edit your question and include all output from `install.packages("arrow")`? (Yes, sorry, _another_ reinstall :-/ )

Comment: Absolutely, no problem. ;-) I looked at them earlier - couldn't see anything out of the ordinary... maybe a sharper set of eyes can. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue was having two conflicting versions of Arrow installed, one through Homebrew (which was installed as a dependency for GDAL), and one downloaded from R. To solve I:

- Uninstalled both versions
- Reinstalled in R (now to v.12)

...and now things are working again.

```r
arrow::arrow_info()
Arrow package version: 12.0.0

Capabilities:
               
acero      TRUE
dataset    TRUE
substrait FALSE
parquet    TRUE
json       TRUE
s3         TRUE
gcs        TRUE
utf8proc   TRUE
re2        TRUE
snappy     TRUE
gzip       TRUE
brotli     TRUE
zstd       TRUE
lz4        TRUE
lz4_frame  TRUE
lzo       FALSE
bz2        TRUE
jemalloc   TRUE
mimalloc   TRUE

Memory:
                  
Allocator mimalloc
Current    0 bytes
Max        0 bytes

Runtime:
                          
SIMD Level          avx512
Detected SIMD Level avx512

Build:
                                    
C++ Library Version           12.0.0
C++ Compiler              AppleClang
C++ Compiler Version 13.0.0.13000029
`
```