How to deal with the error loading parquer data file using read_parquet using R?
I am trying to read a parquet file using the read_parquet function but got the following error:

Error in parquet___arrow___ArrowReaderProperties__Make(isTRUE(use_threads)) :    Cannot call parquet___arrow___ArrowReaderProperties__Make(). See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html for help installing Arrow C++ libraries.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks a ton!
I have installed apache-arrow in my terminal.
This is what I got from arrow_info():
Arrow package version: 15.0.1
Capabilities:
acero     TRUE
...       FALSE
parquet   FALSE
...       FALSE
Memory:

Allocator  system
Current   0 bytes
Max       0 bytes

Runtime:

SIMD Level          none
Detected SIMD Level none

Build:

C++ Library Version           15.0.1
C++ Compiler              AppleClang
C++ Compiler Version 14.0.0.14000029

This is what I got from brew info apache-arrow:
==> apache-arrow: stable 16.0.0 (bottled), HEAD
Columnar in-memory analytics layer designed to accelerate big data
https://arrow.apache.org/
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-arrow/16.0.0 (587 files, 116.2MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-05-08 at 11:04:25
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/a/apache-arrow.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: boost ✘, cmake ✘, ninja ✘
Required: aws-sdk-cpp ✔, brotli ✔, bzip2 ✔, glog ✔, grpc ✔, llvm ✔, lz4 ✔, openssl@3 ✔, protobuf ✔, rapidjson ✔, re2 ✔, snappy ✔, thrift ✔, utf8proc ✔, zstd ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 11,419 (30 days), 36,404 (90 days), 134,830 (365 days)
install-on-request: 6,656 (30 days), 19,949 (90 days), 67,142 (365 days)
build-error: 4 (30 days)


The answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182262/how-to-enable-parquet-in-arrow-in-r
